# How to use CTE with dynamic query pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, common-table-expression, dynamicquery

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

- First I needed to break the dates (start date and end date) into every day from table1 which I did with recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max([EndDate]) FROM table1);
WITH CTE_DateToDays
     AS (SELECT StartDate as Dates
         FROM   table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, Dates)
         FROM   CTE_DateToDays
         WHERE  Dates < @maxdate)

Select Dates from CTE_DateToDays;
```

- Then I wanted to convert rows into columns from table2. Which I did with dynamic pivot, as I did not know the number of columns.

```
DECLARE @TimeBandColms AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

        Select @TimeBandColms = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.TimeBandName) 
                    from table2 t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

Select @TimeBandColms
from
(
 SELECT t.TimeBandID,t.TimeBandName 
                        FROM
                      table2 t
) x
pivot
(
  MAX(TimeBandID)
  for TimeBandName in (" + @TimeBandColms + N")
) piv;
```

Now here I am stuck whenever I combine these two things, sometimes the result set is not what I want or sometimes error with 'Invalid column name' or 'Multi-part identifier could not be bound'.

**NOTE**

> Table1 and Table2 are different tables with nothing in common like key or id.

I have tried many things like union or different approach, but couldn't solve my problem. 
Sorry if I am not more specific, but I am new to this pivot, stuff, and CTE. 
I really need your help.

The result set which I want is something like this...
[image]

Here is my attempt.

```
DECLARE @TimeBandColms AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
select @TimeBandColms = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.TimeBandName) 
                    from table2 t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

   set @query = 'DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max([EndDate]) FROM 
    table1);
   WITH CTE_DateToDays
     AS (SELECT StartDate as Dates
         FROM table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, Dates)
         FROM CTE_DateToDays
         WHERE  Dates < @maxdate)'


  Set @query += N'SELECT ' + @TimeBandColms + N' from 
             (
                SELECT CTE_DateToDays.Dates, t.TimeBandID,t.TimeBandName 
                        FROM CTE_DateToDays,
                      table2 t
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               max(Dates)
  for TimeBandName in (' + @TimeBandColms + N')
            ) piv;'

exec (@query);
```

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: Showed my attempt, edited my question details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @TimeBandColms AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @TimeBandColms = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.TimeBandName) 
                    from table2 t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

   set @query = 'DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max([EndDate]) FROM 
    table1);
   WITH CTE_DateToDays
     AS (SELECT StartDate as Dates
         FROM table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, Dates)
         FROM CTE_DateToDays
         WHERE  Dates < @maxdate)'


  Set @query += N'SELECT Dates, ' + @TimeBandColms + N' from 
             (
                SELECT CTE_DateToDays.Dates, t.TimeBandID, t.TimeBandName 
                        FROM CTE_DateToDays
                            CROSS JOIN table2 t
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               count(TimeBandID)
  for TimeBandName in (' + @TimeBandColms + N')
            ) piv;'

exec (@query);
```

Comment: I tried this early, but the rows returning count of IDs or max number of IDs if changed in pivot
`pivot 
            (
               count(TimeBandID)
  for TimeBandName in (' + @TimeBandColms + N')
            ) piv;'
`
Though result changes in even small modification.

Comment: Still stuck in there. Do you have any idea why result is different when I use query string and without query string? Even though the sql query is same.